# Magento displays ORIGID missing error when trying to "Capture Online" a PayPal Advanced authorized order

Tags: magento-1.8, error, paypal, sales

So when trying to capture an authorized payment from a customer that used their Debit/Credit card using PayPal Advanced Payments Magento displays this error:

> Field format error: ORIGID missing

This only happens when customers use PayPal Advanced not PayPal Express. I know that the issue is that the Parent Transaction ID is not being taken from the initial transaction for whatever reason. I have debugging enabled and do not see any other errors in system.log that are related to this.

[image: Picture showing that Parent Transaction ID is missing]

Please help me figure out what the issue might be, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had set the IPN Address in PayPal and that was causing all the double IPN's. Just be sure to turn that IPN off and capturing online in Magento was a cinch.